# Ruby on Railsでjquery-railsのバージョンを4.0.2にしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

現在以下のようなGemfileを使用していて、

```
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.0.2'
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
gem 'memcachier'
gem 'dalli'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'oauth'
gem "rmagick", '2.13.4', :require => 'RMagick'
group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

bundle installをして成功すると以下のような出力です。

```
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using minitest 4.7.5
Using multi_json 1.11.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 0.3.44
Using activesupport 4.0.13
Using builder 3.1.4
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using rack 1.5.3
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.0.13
Using mime-types 2.5
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.0.13
Using activemodel 4.0.13
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.4
Using arel 4.0.2
Using activerecord 4.0.13
Using coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
Using execjs 2.5.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.0.13
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using dalli 2.7.4
Using hike 1.2.3
Using jbuilder 1.5.3
Using jquery-rails 3.1.2
Using json 1.8.2
Using libv8 3.16.14.7
Using memcachier 0.0.2
Using oauth 0.4.7
Using pg 0.18.1
Using bundler 1.9.8
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.12.3
Using sprockets-rails 2.3.1
Using rails 4.0.13
Using rdoc 4.2.0
Using ref 1.0.5
Using rmagick 2.13.4
Using sass 3.2.19
Using sass-rails 4.0.5
Using sdoc 0.4.1
Using sqlite3 1.3.10
Using therubyracer 0.12.2
Using uglifier 2.7.1
```

ここでjquery-railsの4.0.2を使いたいのですが、
gem 'jquery-rails'
を
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.0.2'
に変更してbundle istallすると以下のようなエラーが出ます。

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    railties (= 4.0.13)

  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 4.0.2) ruby depends on
      railties (= 4.0.13) ruby

    rails (~> 4.0.2) ruby depends on
      railties (= 4.0.13) x64-mingw32

    sass-rails (~> 4.0.3) ruby depends on
      railties (< 5.0, >= 4.0.0) ruby

    sass-rails (~> 4.0.3) ruby depends on
      railties (< 5.0, >= 4.0.0) x64-mingw32

    sass-rails (~> 4.0.3) ruby depends on
      railties (< 5.0, >= 4.0.0) ruby

    sass-rails (~> 4.0.3) ruby depends on
      railties (< 5.0, >= 4.0.0) x64-mingw32

    railties (>= 4.2.0) ruby

    jquery-rails (~> 4.0.2) ruby depends on
      railties (>= 4.2.0) x64-mingw32
```

検索しまくっていろいろぐちゃぐちゃやってみたんですが、さっぱりです。
何かアドバイスを頂けませんでしょうか。よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery-railsのchangelogを見ると jquery-rails 4.0 からは Rails 4.2 以上が必須になっていますね。

https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

> 4.0.0
>   - Minimum dependency set to Rails 4.2

なのでまずはRailsのバージョンアップを先に行う必要がありそうです。

Comment: 4.2にアップグレードするの大変でしたが、無事 jquery-rails 4.0.2 を入れることが出来ました。ありがとうございました。